# find_all is catching my desired tags but find_all_previous isn't (and seems like it should be)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse an HTML document. `find_all_previous()` seems to only be finding the immediate previous item (or at least, it's only catching item #2 of the 2 items it should catch). Am I misunderstanding its use or is there an error in my code?

The HTML I'm trying to parse includes information on six properties, each within `<tr class="property shaded">` or `<tr class="property">` tags. Two are current and four are previous properties; the two sets are divided by a `<h2 id="past-property-deeds">` tag. I only want to collect the information on the current properties. It seems like identifying the "past properties" header tag and using `find_all_previous()` on it should get the results I want (information on properties 1 and 2), but it's only catching the second property and not the first.

```
html_doc = """
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top">
        <h2 id="current-property-deeds">Current Property Deeds (2 Found)</h2>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="reportstableheader">
<span>
Purchase Date: N/A</span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="property shaded">
    Info for current property 1
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="reportstableheader">
<span>
Purchase Date: N/A</span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="property ">
    Info for current property 2
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top">
        <h2 id="past-property-deeds">Past Property Deeds (4 Found)</h2>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="reportstableheader">
<span>
Purchase Date: 01/01/1900</span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="property shaded">
    Info for past property 1
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="reportstableheader">
<span>
Purchase Date: 01/01/1900&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp; Sold Date: 01/01/1900</span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="property ">
    Info for past property 2
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="reportstableheader">
<span>
Purchase Date: N/A&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp; Sold Date: 03/30/2007</span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="property shaded">
    Info for past property 3
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="reportstableheader">
<span>
Purchase Date: 09/22/2000</span>
</td></tr>
<tr class="property ">
    Info for past property 4
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
past_property_header = soup.find("h2", id="past-property-deeds")
all_property_info = soup.find_all("tr", class_=re.compile("^property"))
current_property_only = past_property_header.find_all_previous("tr", class_=re.compile("^property"))
```

`all_property_info` finds all the tags, as expected. However, `current_property_only` is only finding the tag surrounding property 2, when I think it should be catching both 1 and 2. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm getting all previous properties with your code. Not sure what I am missing...

Comment: `print (len(current_property_only))` is showing me I'm getting both property 1 and property 2.

Comment: Weird, I wasn't a minute ago but after closing out of IDLE and reopening now I am, too! I'm going to go back to the original unredacted code and see if it's working there now, too.

Comment: `print (current_property_only)` shows me both: 
`[<tr class="property ">
    Info for current property 2
</tr>, <tr class="property shaded">
    Info for current property 1
</tr>]`

Comment: Shoot, still not catching it in the original code (there's a lot more within those tr tags and most of it is personal information, so I redacted pretty heavily out of laziness but obviously I cut out something important). Let me try to come up with a more accurate bit of sample code.

Comment: Agree with @chitown88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm an idiot. It was returning the correct tags the whole time, I just didn't realize they would show up backwards and I was failing to find the property 1 tag within the mess of the original unredacted HTML. Sorry and thanks, y'all!